# Facebook persistent menu not showing in Messenger (chat bot)

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, facebook, messenger

I'm trying to develop Messenger bot on NodeJS, that would:

1. Create persistent menu
2. Postback message replies

**The issue I'm facing** is that the **persistent menu only showing for myself** (on Desktop and Mobile), but not for anyone else. Tried different accounts, devices, browsers - persistent menu not showing for anyone besides myself. **App is running on Heroku**

So far, I've tried almost everything I've found in stackoverflow, including:

1. Made sure FB App mode is Live (not in Development)
2. Message permissions (including pages_messaging) are granted/subscribed
3. Get started button have been set up
4. Tried replacing /me/ in with FB Page ID
5. Made sure FB Token and Verify Token are correct
6. Tried removing persistent menu and started over

```
let setupPersistentMenu = () => {
    const menuPayload = {
      get_started: {
        payload: "GET_STARTED_PAYLOAD",
      },
      persistent_menu: [
        {
          locale: "default",
          composer_input_disabled: false,
          call_to_actions: [
            {
              title: "First menu item",
              type: "postback",
              payload: "TEST_PAYLOAD",
            }
          ],
        },
      ],
    };
    request(
      {
        uri: "https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/me/messenger_profile",
        qs: { access_token: process.env.FB_PAGE_TOKEN },
        method: "POST",
        json: menuPayload,
      },
      (err, res, body) => {
        if (!err) {
          console.log("Persistent menu have been set up!");
        } else {
          console.error("Unable to set up persistent menu:" + err);
        }
      }
    );
  };
```